# Западает текст на след.блок

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как исправить? когда уменьшаю, текст с верхнего блока налезает на нижний.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код стилей:

```
.block7 {
    margin:  auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    height: 615px;
    background: url(../img/background7.png) no-repeat;  
}

.text11 { 
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #0a0a0b;
    font-size: 36px; 
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.text12 {
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #0a0a0b;
    font-size: 18px; 
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 100px;   
}

                                /*---BLOCK---8*/

.block8 {
    margin:  auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    height: 1090px;
    background: url(../img/background8.png) no-repeat;  

}

.text13 { 
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #0a0a0b;
    font-size: 30px; 
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 32px;   
}

.text14 {
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #0a0a0b;
    font-size: 17px; 
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;  
}
```

Comment: Сделать адаптивную верстку.

Comment: я пытался,задавал в % ширину, потом при эмуляции большого экрана,у меня текст остаеться по середине а bg сьезжает влево...

Comment: Я о том, что в мобильной верстке можно блоки сделать не в ширину, а в высоту

Comment: Вообще не понимаю о чем ты( это обычная верстка,просто я сделал экран узким чтобы семулировать экран мобильного. Мне через медиа как-то задать высоты ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: Покажите css, наверняка проблема с position

Comment: вот код, блок 6-7-8-9 и так далее, в блоках где текст длинный беда